# Error: npm install -g angular-cli | npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

> Error while running: npm install -g angular-cli

```
C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v7.5.0
C:\Windows\System32>npm -v
4.1.2
C:\Users\Chiranjeevi>npm -v minimatch
4.1.2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Chiranjeevi>npm install -g angular-cli
```

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue 
C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty) 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): 
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed. 
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\yallist-2cab1649\package.json.797219503 
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename  'C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\yallist-2cab1649\package.json.797219503' ->  'C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\yallist-2cab1649\package.json' 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\yallist-2cab1649\package.json.797219503' -> 'C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\yallist-2cab1649\package.json' 
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself 
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\npm-debug.log

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should execute `npm cache clean` instead of `npm clear cache` (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache).

Regarding `npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.`: There is an [open angular cli issue concerning rxjs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4357). As a workaraound, you can execute `npm install -g rxjs`.

Additionally, the npm package name for angular cli changed from angular-cli to @angular-cli.

That is, the following might help:

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g rxjs
npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: `npm install -g rxjs` was enough for me

Comment: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\css-parse-3e224c20\package.json.27297876' -> 'C:\Users\Chiranjeevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\css-parse-3e224c20\package.json'

Comment: It couldn't find npm in global, so you might need to re-install node_module in global by re-installing node.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm clear cache`

and than `npm install -g angular-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest Nodejs(LTS version) installed. 
Try following

1. npm i npm -g
2. npm cache clean
3. npm install -g @angular/cli